# Rails Migration - what's the point of self.up and self.down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

I was wondering what those meant:

```
class ChangeTimeColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

as sometimes Rails just creates a migration like this:

```
class ChangeTimeColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

Would appreciate any clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is so you can reverse the migration if you have made a mistake.

```
rake db:rollback   #this will rollback the most recent migration


rake db:rollback STEP=3  #this will rollback 3 of them
```

I add self.up and self.down to all my migrations, and if there is a migration that is not possible to reverse, you can not include down or raise an exception in down. Check out section 4.1 in this guide ====> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-up-down-methods

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the current version of rails, self.up and self.down were the standard format, i.e. in Rails 3.0.x

self.up is used to define the behavior of what should happen on a `rake db:migrate` where as self.down defined the behavior for a `rake db:rollback`. Change is relatively new and is generally used where self.down behavior can be inferred in a trivial way.

Answer (score 0):

Every INSERT, UPDATE etc you do in the self.up, you do the opposite in the self.down.

It is important if you have to rollback these migration later due to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Self.up for any model to insert attributes into model table that is written in it.

while self.down is reverse of it.